# Samba permissions don't apply

Tags: samba

All groups exist and the users are in their belonging defined group.

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
admin users = @admin
browseable = no
read only = no
create mask = 0750
```

(Users can't write in their homes. Why?)

```
[pi]
comment = pi Home Folder
valid users = @admin
write list = @admin
path = /home/pi
read only = no
browseable = yes
```

(Users from admin group have no write rights. Why?)

```
[personal]
comment = files
valid users = danny
path = /home/danny/personal
read only = no
browseable = no
```

(User danny has no write access.)

```
[downloads]
comment = Download Folder
valid users = @users
write list = @admin
path = /home/danny/downloads
read only = no
guest ok = no
```

(Admins should have write access but they haven't got it.)

Could you help me analyze the problem here?

Comment: Does _anybody_ have write access to your samba from the windowses?

Answer (score 0):

**For Admins :** 
1. All Admin users should be added to the write list i.e. @admin.
2. All Admin users should be added to the valid users i.e. @users.
3. Set correct group permission on the writable directories.
4. Set password using "smbpasswd"

Don't forget to set the Selinux Context and Boolean if Selinux is enabled

Comment: I that and it still doesnt work :_

Comment: What error are you getting? Unable to login, or unable to access share, or unable to access home dir?

Comment: i cant write to any shares as user of the admin grp

Comment: Is selinux enabled??? Set correct selinux context. You don't have permission to write the group or directory. Check that.